# Looking for a clever way to render multiple children component dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Modal component composed of a `<Header>` and a `<Content>`.

I want both children `<Header>` and `<Content>` to be rendered dynamically based on a given value ('modal type').

My first intuition was to create an object storing modal components like:

```
export const useModalDetails = (onClose = () => {}) => {
    const [ modalDetails, setModalDetails ] = useMergeState({
        Header: () => <div/>,
        Content: () => <div/>,
        onClose,
    });
    return [modalDetails, setModalDetails];
};
```

Then a function to set modal details base on the value type:

```
const onChangeModalType = (type) => {
  if (type === 'type1') {
   setModalDetails({
     Header: () => <div>Modal Header Type 1</dov>,
     Content: () => <div>Modal Content Type 1</div>,
     open: true

   })
  } else if (type === 'type2') {
   setModalDetails({
     Header: () => <div>Modal Header Type 2</dov>,
     Content: () => <div>Modal Content Type 2</div>,
     open: true
   })
  }
}
```

Then I can use the react-hook in the `<Modal>` component:

```
import SemanticModal from 'semantic-ui-react'

const Modal = () => {

 const [ modalDetails, setModalDetails ] = useMergeState({
        Header: () => <></>,
        Content: () =>  <></>,
        open: false,
    });
    return [modalDetails, setModalDetails];
    
  onChangeModalType('type2')

 return (
  <>
  <SemanticModal
     Header={modalDetails.Header}
     Content={modalDetails.Content}
     open={modalDetails.open}
  />
  <button onClick={() => onChangeModalType('type1')}>load type 1</button>
   <button onClick={() => onChangeModalType('type2')}>load type 2</button>
  </>
 )
}
```

Bear in mind I have 12 different types of content, and header for a `<Modal>`, that means 12 `if, else` statements for each.

Do you have any idea how I could develop that in a smarter, clever, more readable, maintainable... WAY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're decided on having an individual modal component that switches behaviour based on state/props you could approach it like this:

```
const modals = {
  type1: {
    Header: <div>Modal1 Header</div>,
    Content: <div>Modal1 Content</div>,
    open: true,
  },
  type2: {
    Header: <div>Modal2 Header</div>,
    Content: <div>Modal2 Content</div>,
    open: true,
  },
};

const Modal = ({type}) => {
  const [modalType, setModalType] = useState(type);
  const { Header, Content, open } = modals[modalType];

  return (
    <>
      <SemanticModal
        Header={Header}
        Content={Content}
        open={open}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

An alternative to consider is creating a reusable `BaseModal` component which you extend into a seperate component for each use case:

```
const BaseModal = ({ Header, Content, open }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SemanticModal Header={Header} Content={Content} open={open} />
    </>
  );
};

const Modal1 = () => {
  return (
    <BaseModal
      Header={<div>Modal1 Header</div>}
      Content={<div>Modal1 Content</div>}
      open={true}
    />
  );
};
```

The nice thing about this pattern is that you still get to share the common elements of *all* modals whilst selectively injecting the parts that need to differ

Comment: something like this for each type ?
<SemanticModal>
<header>Header Type 1</header>
<content>content type 1</content>